# Convert BSTR to int

Tags: c++, winapi

Does any one know how can I convert a BSTR to an int in VC++ 2008

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [pass a BSTR safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980/how-do-you-efficiently-copy-bstr-to-wchart) to any function expecting a `wchar_t *`. So you can use [_wtoi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c(VS.80).aspx)().

Comment: You can't, NULL is a valid BSTR value.

Answer (score 7):

Google suggests [`VarI4FromStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HRESULT VarI4FromStr(
  _In_   LPCOLESTR strIn,
  _In_   LCID lcid,
  _In_   ULONG dwFlags,
  _Out_  LONG *plOut
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the [_wtoi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c(VS.80).aspx) function:

```
int i = _wtoi( mybstr );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use ::VarI4FromStr(...).

Answer (score 1):

```
BSTR s = SysAllocString(L"42");
int i = _wtoi(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use boost::lexical_cast<>

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t     plop[]  = L"123";
    int value   = boost::lexical_cast<int>(plop);

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

The cool thing is that lexical_cast<>
It will work for any types that can be passed through a stream and its **type safe**!

Answer (score 1):

This is a method I use to parse values out of strings.  It's similar to [Boost's lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

```
std::wistringstream iss(mybstr);   // Should convert from bstr to wchar_t* for the constructor
iss >> myint;                      // Puts the converted string value in to myint
if(iss.bad() || iss.fail())
{
   // conversion failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [VarI4FromStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221194.aspx) like others pointed out. `BSTR` is not `wchar_t*` because of differences in their [NULL semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx) (`SysStringLen(NULL)` is ok, but `wcslen(NULL)` is not).